# Launching external apps and waiting for them to launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to launch a list of supporting apps. I then have to wait until those apps have finished launching before continuing to execute code. Here is what I have right now:

```
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
int i = 0;

while (i < [launchApps count]) {
    [ws launcApplication: [launchApps objectAtIndex: i]];
    ++i
}

while (![self appsFinishedLaunching]) {
    NSLog(@"loop");
    sleep(1);
}
```

then later:

```
- (BOOL)appsFinishedLaunching
{
    BOOL doneLaunching = NO;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            int i = 0;
            while (i < [launchApps count]) {
                NSWorkspace *nws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
                NSArray *runningApps = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[nws runningApplications]];
                for (NSRunningApplication *app in runningApps) {
                    if ([[app localizedName] isEqualToString:[launchApps objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                        if ([app isFinishedLaunching]) {
                            [launchApps removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            }
    if ([launchApps count] == 0)
        doneLaunching = YES;

    [pool drain];

    return doneLaunching;
}
```

If I run manually open all the Apps in launchApps I get one "loop" in console and all is well. If I run this code and let it launch the apps it goes in to an infinite loop. It seems like the NSRunningApplications objects in my shared workspace aren't being updated and I'm not sure I understand why. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you `waiting` or `eating` for them? The title is a bit funny.

Comment: Typos, sorry! Thanks Chris for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple Docs on NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> @property(readonly, getter=isFinishedLaunching) BOOL finishedLaunching
>
> The value of this property corresponds to the running application having received an NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification notification internally. Some applications do not post this notification (applications that do not rely on NSApplication) and so are never reported as finished launching.

If the application you've launched doesn't post the notification, you can't use this property.

The question is, is the application you're trying to launch a Cocoa app?  If not, you might have to investigate other launching functions; the C function `exec` might work, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing with cocoa apps. It does work if the apps were launched prior to running my code, so it does see them as finishedLaunching as long as everything has finished launching prior to the first time the `isFinishedLaunching` loop runs.

Comment: Hmm...okay, have you checked to make sure `[app localizedName]` is returning a name that is actually equal to any of your `[launchApps objectAtIndex:i]`'s?  You might want to put in some `NSLog()`s to check this, or set some breakpoints and debug that section.

Comment: Yeah, I just put an NSLog() statement in to test the `[app localizedName]` the `[launchApps objectAtIndex:i]` and the `[app isFinishedLaunching]` If the apps are pre launched everything comes out as expected. If the code launches the app the app names are still the same, but the `[app isFinishedLaunching]` never changes to `YES`, it just continually loops as returns `NO`.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark now, but maybe you have to register the notification if you launch the app?

Comment: Well, if I put a break point after I launch the apps, and wait for the apps to launch before continuing on I get the proper `isFinishedLaunching` response. I've banged my head against a wall on this for the last few days. I think I'll replace this mess with a `sleep(5)` and hope that is long enough in most cases.

Comment: @Kris -- very odd, and I don't blame you for being frustrated.  I can't think of any other reason for it, except to say that when dealing with multiple processes, sometimes things are strange.  It might be that you reach the `appsFinishedLaunching` method befor things get registered, and `nws` doesn't have updated info...I'm not sure (and that sounds wonky).  What if you try a smaller `sleep()` in the actual loop itself?  Something on the order of a tenth of a second?